# MySQL is really unstable - Considering migration

Tags: mysql, database

How can I make a more robust database server? I know this is a pretty general question but I'm getting all sort of errors and downtimes using MySQL with a simple service that does some selects and 2 inserts. Nothing complex, no JOINs...

At first I got my host blocked from the DB server because of many connections, so I increased the max_used_connections parameter. And my client is actually closing the connections and handling the pool correctly.

For some days it worked OK. Today I woke up and the MySQL server was down. Tried to restart it with `service mysql restart` and it failed. Tried to connect and error 1040: too many connections.
So I couldn't even restart the server.

I did `killall mysqld` and tried to start the server with `service mysql start`. Service wouldn't start. Run `su - mysql -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &"` and the server finally started.

I also increased max_connections limit because the server would just die after some seconds when starting it today.

Then one table was corrupt `ERROR 144 (HY000): Table '<table_name>' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed`

Tried to `REPAIR <table_name>` but after some time the server died again `ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away`. Tried this same process (killall up to here) about 3 times, everytime the server died.

Now I'm running `REPAIR <table_name> QUICK` and the server seems not to be dying, but it's taking a really long time to fix a 200k row table.

By the way, I only have two tables, one with 200k rows and another with 11M rows. I peak about 2000 concurrent users, which result in about 100 queries per second max.

Is it normal that MySQL crashes this easy? Should I migrate to other more scalable databases like Cassandra? I actually prefer a relational database for my case (table results has a request_id, FK of a requests table that has a key_id FK of a keys table), but wouldn't mind losing the relational benefits for an actually good uptime.

Comment: Migrating to some other software doesn't mean that they have some "magic" code that makes it work on bad hardware. First off, you don't want to have anything connecting / disconnecting from MySQL. You want to have persistent connections. Second, you need to have proper hardware for the db - this means a good solid state drive and sufficient RAM - RAM for keeping working data set in it. Third, you need to configure your MySQL - it comes with a config that makes it run "ok"-ish on 2001. computers. To answer - it's not normal for MySQL to crash.

Comment: MySQL is a pretty robust and reliable service.  Crashes ar not common, not are they to be considered normal behaviour.  Please let us know what operating system distribution you are using, as well as the MySQL version.

Comment: You also appear to be running this from a virtual host - please give us RAM and disk specs.  The errors in restarting MySQL are related tot he OS rather than to MySQL itself.

Comment: @N.B. I actually let my go client handle the connection pool and use prepared statements that reuse connections when necessary and all that stuff, that's what I meant with that part.

I have a i5-750 with 16GB of ram. Not using a SSD tho, I have a 2TB HDD. OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @JasonD i5-750 with 16GB of ram. 2TB HDD. OS is Ubuntu 14.04. MySQL version is 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: mySQL is used in production environments all around the world. It’s not inherently unstable.

Comment: @Pekka웃 that's why I went with MySQL and why I'm asking how to make it more robust. Also wanted to know if given my resources it would be better to use other software: I read that it's not easy/cheap to scale with MySQL

Comment: Do you have supervisor installed which boots mysql back up? It's weird that killall didn't work, I can't remember if I've ever seen it not work. I also have no idea why so many downvotes, it's a solid question, but the part missing are all of the symptoms so we can find the cause. As mentioned in the posted answer, this smells like a bad HDD. Which table engine do you use (please don't say MyISAM) and can you post the db config?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your question (*Is it normal that MySQL crashes this easy? Should I migrate to other more scalable databases like Cassandra?* ) can be answered objectively, so here is my subjective answer:

No, it's not normal, and you probably shouldn't migrate, since you want a relational database and MySQL is well supported and really well known.

More info about your problem (also subjective):

MySQL is really really stable.  I have MySQL services that have been running for years with regular use and have not had issues.  I'm sure many others have had similar experiences. Many large companies use MySQL with great success.

What concerns me is that killall and service restart didn't work.  Especially since you are running on an Ubuntu LTS version that is over 2 years old, and hence pretty stable itself.  While I cannot say this with absolute certainty, it looks like you may have hardware issues, or at the very least a corrupt hard drive.  You may also have software and/or kernel options or settings that are causing problems.

My suggestion to you would be to do a full hardware check (at a minimum check RAM and HDD), and do a full reinstall.

Comment: I have not found a version since 8.0.21 (8.0.32 is the latest currently) that doesn't segfault in my web app test suite which does basic inserts, deletes and updates - albiet with a good number of foreign keys and such - but nothing unusual. Reported bug to tracker and it was verified but still not fixed after many months.. You'd think segfault would be important to fix, seems stability took a turn for the worse. Really really don't want to move but considering move to MariaDb.